Behaviour of Room DB in Android after play store update
I'm using a prepopulated room db in my android project with .createFromAsset(DB_FILE_PATH). Users cant change the content of the db. When app starts it creates 3 files in data/data/package_name... (.db ; .db-shm ; .db-wal) and all the db reads are done from there.
When existing user updates app from play store, with an updated DB in assets/database/database.db (tables stay the same, only a few data tweaks) what happens with those 3 db files (.db ; .db-shm ; .db-wal), or better question, will the user see updated data from assets or will old data still be used from 3 .db file from data/data...?

If you didnt do anything to handle the new database changes from the assets folder, the user will still have the old data/schema

OK, that was my thinking, just wanted to be sure :)

createFromAsset handles a single file it is not intended to be used for a database that has not been fully checkpointed, if -wal and -shm files exist then the database has not been fully checkpointed.
Furthermore, createFromAsset will only be invoked if the database file does not exist, irrespective of a new/changed version of the asset.
However, you can use a changed asset and apply those changes, if the App can detect the change. If the change includes a change to the schema then this could be sufficient to indicate the changed asset and a migration could then re-copy the asset.
You may find How to Update Database from Assets Folder in App and the links therein useful.
If the change requires the retention of changes made by the user, then this would very likely add complexities associated with detecting what is user changed data as opposed to core asset based data.
